# jquery: remove first two children?

Tags: jquery

i have three td's inside of #mainmenu.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" id="mainmenu">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                something
            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                something
            </td>
            <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                something
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove the first two td's inside of my table, how can i do that?

```
$('#mainmenu td').remove();
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the [less than selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XbGSV/) is a jsfiddle

```
$('#mainmenu td:lt(2)').remove();
```

Comment: I think I've had too much wine. My initial instinct was `$("table").find("td:eq(0), td:eq(1)").remove();`. How awful! I've answered this at least 10 times before. No more wine for me.

Comment: @karim79 - Haha, there is no law against intoxicated coding. Your SO points may suffer for it tho!

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
 $('#mainmenu td:first').remove();
 $('#mainmenu td:first').remove();
```

Comment: oh , yeah better use Josiah's answer